# backboneforce.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm loading my dependencies with require.js and I'm getting this error:

```
backboneforce.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My Config file:

```
    require.config({
    // Require is defined in /scripts, so just the remaining path (and no ext needed)
    'baseUrl': 'js/',
    'paths': {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery",
        "underscore": "libs/underscore",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone",
        "bootstrap": "libs/bootstrap",
        "text": "libs/text",
        "notify": "libs/notify",
        "backboneForce":"libs/backboneforce",
        "forceTK":"libs/forcetk/forcetk",
        "forceTKUI":"libs/forcetk/forcetkui"
    },
    'shim': {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap'
        },

        backbone: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            'exports': '_'
        },
        forceTK:{
            deps:['jquery'],
            exports:'forcetk'
        }
    }

});

require([

    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app'
], function (App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    App.initialize();
});
```

and here is my app.js:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap',
    'backboneForce',
    'forceTK',
    'forceTKUI',
    'notify',
    'router/navigationRouter'
], function ($, _, Backbone, bootstrap, bbforce, forcetk, forcetkui, notify, Router) {
    var initialize = function () {
        Router.initialize();
        console.log(bbforce);
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

In my browser network tab, all dependencies are loaded, but I'm getting this error for forceTK, forceTKUI and backboneForce.

Comment: Look at the network tab, what do you see with http response status? All 200s? or do you have a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the path to the `backboneforce` file is wrong and the server is returning a 404 HTML page.

The following line:

```
"backboneForce":"libs/backboneforce",
```

should probably be

```
"backboneForce":"libs/backboneforce/backboneforce", // or backbone.force
```

## How does require `paths` work?

Paths inside the `paths` option are just aliases. If you want to point to a module, you must include the file name without the extension.

If you have the following directory structure:

```
lib
├───backboneforce
│   └───backbone.force.js
```

The path should be `lib/backboneforce/backbone.force`.

## Where is the `<` coming from?

When you make a request with a path to a non-existent file, the server will often return some sort of default 404 error message or it will redirect to a default page (like the home page).

Here's what Stack Overflow returns:

[image: wrong path 404 error]

The `<` comes from `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the first line of the response, which the browser tries to interpret as JavaScript.

Comment: no the files are loaded properly as my network tab tells me. I tried your solution but still get the same error.

Comment: @b0ss Look inside the backboneforce force file, it probably require another file, of which the path isn't set correctly in your config.

Comment: @b0ss what's inside the `libs/backboneforce` directory? Please add this to your question.

Comment: solved the problem. @Emile Bergeron it was the containing code which was HTML and that was the problem thank you.